# Can JUnit 5 actually inject extension instances?

Tags: java, junit5, junit5-extension-model

The documentation for `@RegisterExtension` mentions something about injection of the instance:

> the extension will be registered after the test class has been instantiated and after all
> `TestInstancePostProcessor`s have been given a chance to post-process the test instance
> (potentially injecting the instance of the extension to be used into the annotated field).

*Are* there any post-processors in JUnit which can do this for extensions automatically, or is this just talking about things people might build in the future?

In our case, I found that many of our extensions turn out to be like this:

```java
    @RegisterExtension
    public final TempFolderExtension temp = new TempFolderExtension();

    @RegisterExtension
    public final SomeFactoryExtension factory = new SomeFactoryExtension(temp);
```

A container like PicoContainer could automatically figure out how to construct the instances.

It would be really nifty if we could just write,

```java
    @RegisterExtension
    public TempFolderExtension temp;

    @RegisterExtension
    public SomeFactoryExtension factory;
```

And either an annotation processor or a runtime injector could fill in the rest.

Dependencies between this sort of extension also has implications for the order they should run in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer: No, it is not possible, when using `@RegisterExtension` you have to construct your extension instance manually.

Read [https://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/user-guide/#extensions](https://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/user-guide/#extensions-registration-programmatic) 5.2.2

Comment: 5.2.2 is literally the section which contains the quote that I included in the first paragraph of the question so one might assume that I have read it.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if such an extension exists. I think it is more common in the JUnit 5 ecosystem to register extensions with [`@ExtendWith`](https://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/user-guide/#extensions-registration-declarative). The extension can then inject interfaces into the test.

```java
@ExtendWith(TempFolderExtension.class)
static final class SomeTest {

    public TempFolderInterface temp;

    @Test
    void test() {
        ...
    }
}
```

However, if you want to have an extension as proposed in the question, it would be simple to implement one. Here is `ExtensionInjector`, a working implementation for such extension.

```java
final class ExtensionInjector implements TestInstancePostProcessor {
    @Override
    public void postProcessTestInstance(Object testInstance, ExtensionContext context) throws Exception {
        List<Field> fields = ReflectionSupport.findFields(
                testInstance.getClass(),
                field -> AnnotationSupport.isAnnotated(field, RegisterExtension.class),
                HierarchyTraversalMode.BOTTOM_UP);
        for (Field field : fields) {
            field.trySetAccessible();
            if (field.get(testInstance) == null) {
                field.set(testInstance, ReflectionSupport.newInstance(field.getType()));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

You can add this extension to your project [as documented in the JUnit 5 User Guide](https://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/user-guide/#extensions-registration).